# HTML CSS aligning divs and text next to image

Tags: html, css

Hello I have read a few articles of people with similar struggles to me but none of the solutions seem to work for me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39UI5.jpg)

[image]

I am trying to create something like the picture attached but the text always seems to go underneath the image, whatever CSS I edit.

```css
.newstitle {
  background-color: #ffed00;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.newspic img {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 300px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">

  <div class="newspic">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/500x300" alt="Photo placeholder">
  </div>

  <div class="newstitle">
    D'votion presents his bassline remix of Post Malone's Rockstar
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Typically, what you'll need to do is divide the content up into to halves, or columns, then wrap these columns in a containing element. One column, say the first, will contain the image container (`.newspic`), the other will contain all nested text content (`.newstitle` and any other content, like excerpts, meta and call to action buttons, etc.). Once you have this basic structure in place, you can properly align components as intended through various methods (`float` properties, `display: inline-block`, or `flex-box` properties, etc.)

Comment: Add some borders to your css so you can see the div width. They might just take up 100% of the space they have.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! both of you are life savers! :)

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `<div>` container for the `<img>` and passed the `class="newspic"` to the image. Then I positioned both `.newstitle` and `.newspic` relatively to their `parent` and gave them `width:70%` and `width:30%;` respectively.

The key here, since you are using `paddings` is to include `box-sizing:border-box;` into both classes so the paddings are taken account for when calculating the width.

**Here is the working code:** (run the snippet & try full screen)

```css
.main{
}

.newstitle
{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:70%;
  background-color: #ffed00;
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight : bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.newspic
{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  padding: 20px;
  width:30%;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
    <img class="newspic" src="https://i2.wp.com/farm3.staticflickr.com/2883/9197736562_3cce3c65ee_o.jpg" alt="Photo placeholder" />

  <div class="newstitle">
    <p>D'votion presents his bassline remix of Post Malone's Rockstar</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just place the text container inside the div with the image.

```
<section class="">
<div class="newspic">
<img src="Art portfolio/illustrations/IMG_0844.JPG" alt="Photo placeholder">
<div class="newstitle">
 D'votion presents his bassline remix of Post Malone's Rockstar
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this instead:

HTML

```
<section class="main">

<div class="newspic">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476124861542-44354851e622?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&s=eac3b3d003e83c809de608dd6dcc3857" alt="Photo placeholder">
</div>

<div class="newstitle">
  D'votion presents his bassline remix of Post Malone's Rockstar
</div>

</section>
```

CSS

```
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.newspic {
  width: 50%;
}
.newspic img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

You can view it here: https://codepen.io/jobaelish/pen/QaxXww

This is a simple fix.

Nonetheless, if you're HTML is not being affected, then you need to make sure your stylesheet is linked in your document `head` element properly.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PATHTOCSSHERE">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are "several" ways to accomplish this task. One way is to just add display inline on your side text and float the picture to the left. Also set a width on your picture. You could also use flexbox or you could of just used float with the text in the same div as the picture.

```css
  
.newstitle{

  background-color: #ffed00;
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight : bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline;
}

.newspic img{
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
padding: 20px;
  height: 300px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">

<div class="newspic">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2018/zhou-youguangs-112th-birthday-5826412689752064-law.gif"  alt="Photo placeholder">
</div>

<div class="newstitle">
  D'votion presents his bassline remix of Post Malone's Rockstar
</div>

</section>
```